# Clearing adjacent cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in the range `A9:G15`, set in the table where `A9:G9` contains the headers.

I am using a macro that clears some adjacent cells of adjacent columns in the range `B10:G15` once `$A$10` is cleared or changed.

The macro seems to only clear the adjacent cells in Range `B10:G10`, while leaving the data in the range `B11:B15`. This is because I am not clearing the cells in `A11:A15` as I don't want the users to enter data in Range `A11:A15`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A10:A15")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B10:B15")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C10:C15")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D10:D15")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

In an attempt to fix this, I entered this formula in the cells of `A11:A15` *`IF($A$10="","", $A$10)`*, and I set the font of `A11:A15` to grey color and the fill to grey so the users won't see the repetition in these cells and so they know that they should not enter data in those cells.

However, it seems that the macro doesn't recognize the "" in `A11:A15` (which is returned by the formula) as an act of clearing any of the cells in `A11:A15`.

Note that I need the macro to be applied to any new row inserted in the table later on.

Comment: It's not very clear what your aim is, but I think you need to define the range of your table using variables and then simply clear the whole range? Something like `Range(Cells(x,y).address, Cells(a,b).address).ClearContents` where `x,y,a,b` are row and column numbers

Comment: make some examples of your actual need: you seem to need event triggering "once $A$10 is cleared or changed", but then your event macro cares about other cells, too

Comment: @DisplayName Sorry for the confusion! I need the event triggering to clear all the mentioned cells in the macro above once $A$10 is cleared. 

$A11:$A15 will be locked as no user will be entering data here. But the selected cells in B10:G15 should be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

**""** is not treated as **Nothing** in Excel, I think this is the problem. Could you try changing your `IF` conditions in VBA accordingly?

**EDIT:**

Could you try changing below part

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A10:A15")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
    Target.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
```

to

```
If Range("$A10").Value = "" Then
    For i = 0 To 5
        For j = 1 To 5
            Target.Offset(i, j).ClearContents
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: Could you please help me change it accordingly?
I am not very good with VBA. I merely got this code from the web and adjusted it according to my Range of data.

Comment: You are not actually making any changes to `A11:A15`, when do you exactly want the Cells `B11:B15` to be cleared?

Comment: Yes, I am not making any changes to A11:A15.

Comment: Yes, I am not making any changes to A11:A15. 
When $A10 is cleared, I would like to clear cells B10:E15